# OrientDB Client Side Javascript API Support

Tags: orientdb

I want to connect Orient DB from client side JS and want to fire queries and display the output on web application.

Could someone point me to client side orient db javascript library?
Orient DB site has following link and it is not working.

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/blob/master/server/src/site/js/orientdb-api.js

Comment: yes this the question exactly i need a solution. http://stackoverflow.com/q/41179681/7290141

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the new Javascript driver for OrientDB with a Blueprints/Gremlin like syntax. This library is in Alpha status.
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-js

If you're using Node.js, we suggest to use

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientjs

instead.

**UPDATE**

For more information look at this link: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Javascript-Driver.html

Hope it helps.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Do you have a sample examples for 
1. Connecting to the Orient DB with username/password
2. Firing queries and fetching the output in JavaScript

Comment: Could you please also comment on what is the suggested approach to connect to Orient DB to achieve good performance, client side JS or Java APIs?

Comment: You'll find everything into the link of the OrientDB's official guide that I posted you in my update

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: If my answer is correct, could you select my answer as best, please?