# OrientDB Client-side firing query

Tags: java, html, orientdb

I had a task to create a simple application using eclipse as a tool and OrientDB through java, u can look into the code that I have posted below and I have connected to the OrientDB server, I'm getting the output on the console window but I want to command from the web page that is on client side. Please help me out in firing queries on the client side.

```java
package test;

import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandSQL;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Vertex;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientEdge;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraph;

public class Sample {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Sample sam = new Sample();
sam.run();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void run() {

        OrientGraph graph = new OrientGraph("plocal:C:\\Users\\Labuser\\Desktop\\orientdb-community-2.2.12\\databases\\OBD", "admin", "admin");
        graph.createVertexType("Person");
        graph.createVertexType("Address");

        Vertex vPerson = graph.addVertex("class:Person");
        vPerson.setProperty("firstName", "John");
        vPerson.setProperty("lastName", "Smith");

        Vertex vAddress = graph.addVertex("class:Address");
        vAddress.setProperty("street", "Van Ness Ave.");
        vAddress.setProperty("city", "San Francisco");
        vAddress.setProperty("state", "California");

        Vertex vPerson1 = graph.addVertex(null);



        OrientEdge eLives = graph.addEdge("class:lives", vPerson, vAddress, null);
        for (Vertex v : (Iterable<Vertex>) graph.command(
                new OCommandSQL(
                    "SELECT  * FROM V"
                  )).execute()) {
            System.out.println("- Bought: " + v);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: please anyone help me out in solving this

Comment: Just connect in remote and not in plocal from the client where you want the output to the OrientDB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but Can u suggest me with any query so that I can understand.

Comment: Can u please send me any tutorial in order to connect in remote??!

Comment: To use your code as a java client with remote connection, ca use the same syntax for console client (remote:hostname/dbname), as documented here: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Console-Command-Connect.html . You might also be interested in servlets : http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Java-Web-Apps.html , http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Java-Web-Apps.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion have you got any demo you made use of it